# Dictionary comprehension to build list of lists: referencing the current value for a key during comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a list of lists based on hashes. That is, I want a list of lists of items that hash the same.  Is this possible in a single-line comprehension?

Here is the simple code that works without comprehensions:

```
def list_of_lists(items):
    items_by_hash = defaultdict(list)
    for item in items:
        words_by_key[hash(item)].append(item)
    return words_by_key.values()
```

For example, let's say we have this simple hash function:

```
def hash(string):
    import __builtin__
    return __builtin__.hash(string) % 10
```

Then,

```
>>> l = ['sam', 'nick', 'nathan', 'mike']
>>> [hash(x) for x in l]
[4, 3, 2, 2]
>>>
>>> list_of_lists(l)
[['nathan', 'mike'], ['nick'], ['sam']]
```

Is there any way I could do this in a comprehension? I need to be able to reference the dictionary I'm building mid-comprehension, in order to append the next item to the list-value.

This is the best I've got, but it doesn't work:

```
>>> { hash(word) : [word] for word in l }.values()
[['mike'], ['nick'], ['sam']]
```

It obviously creates a new list every time which is not what I want. I want something like

```
{ hash(word) : __this__[hash(word)] + [word] for word in l }.values()
```

or

```
>>> dict([ (hash(word), word) for word in l ])
{2: 'mike', 3: 'nick', 4: 'sam'}
```

but this causes the same problem.

Comment: You say you want to create a list of sets, but then later you seem to be creating a dictionary.  What is the output you actually want?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a single comprehension.  It's probably possible to concoct a complicated one-liner using `itertools.groupby`, but it would be much less readable than a loop.  So I'd say just stick with an explicit loop.

Comment: @BrenBarn: You rang? :P

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, I meant "set" in the mathematical sense, but I do indeed want a list of lists. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[y[1] for y in x[1]] for x in itertools.groupby(sorted((hash(y), y)
  for y in items), operator.itemgetter(0))]
```

Comment: Just what I had in mind!  And confirms my belief that there's no reason to do it this way. :-)

Comment: Yeah, definitely don't do it this way if you can help it.

Comment: Unless you want to tag the question with [tag:perl]. Then everything goes

Comment: By the way, why do you need itemgetter?  It will automatically sort by the first tuple element anyway.

Comment: @BrenBarn: `itemgetter()` is passed to `groupby()`, not `sorted()`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: The reason you don't want to do this is that apart from readability, it is also algorithmically more complex; the sort raises this to O(NlogN) where you had a O(N) algorithm by using a `defaultdict` and a simple loop.

Comment: I agree with @MartijnPieters. I was hoping there'd be a way to do it all at once, without having to unique the list. But yeah, way to go! :)